# Can I invest online in an ETF that tracks the Nasdaq in Ireland?

Tags: etf, nasdaq, ireland

I'm an Irish citizen and have recently moved to Ireland to work after living most of my life in South Africa. I have pension investments in South Africa and in Ireland, as well as other investments. I'm looking to sell those non-pension investments which aren't performing very well, and invest some of the proceeds in an index ETF that tracks the NASDAQ Top 100 in the US to diversify my mostly local retirement investments a bit. I'm looking to do this long term, 5 years minimum, more likely 10+, and I'm specifically looking for a low fee online brokerage that provides access to an ETF that tracks NASDAQ. Something like [E-Trade](https://us.etrade.com/home) or [Robinhood](https://signup.robinhood.com/), but I can't use them since I don't have a US address. I've also found Degiro and iShares, but neither of them seem to offer an ETF that tracks NASDAQ specifically.

Comment: I think you're confusing brokers and mutual fund companies. E-Trade and robinhood do not "provide" funds - they allow you to trade funds provided by other companies. What you want is a European broker that can trade US ETFs (or an EUR ETF that tracks the NASDAQ).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I've edited my question. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Yes it does. Have you looked at [EQQQ](https://etf.invesco.com/en/product/invesco-eqqq-nasdaq-100-ucits-etf-dist/trading-information)?

Comment: Ahh, That's exactly what I'm looking for. Didn't know to search for EQQQ

Comment: If that's what you're looking for I'll add it as an answer - I wasn't certain if you were looking for an EU fund or a broker that can trade US funds.

Comment: EU fund and UCITS preferably

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103909/discussion-between-sirlark-and-d-stanley).

Comment: @DStanley EQQQ tracks the Nasdaq 100 [whereas](https://www.financialexpress.com/investing-abroad/featured-stories/nasdaq-100-vs-nasdaq-composite-index-performance-and-differences-explained/2179594/) OP specified the Nasdaq Composite.

Comment: @nanoman In fairness, I'm new to this, hence my (I believe) conservative approach in investment. I used the term "composite" very loosly. I'm interested to know what the difference is between composite vs tracking the top 100

Comment: @sirlark That's what the "whereas" link in my comment describes. :)